# 3 commas and 1 or, where does assignment go?

Tags: commas

"They shall be laid before the bishop and his counselors, two of the elders, or high priests, such as he shall appoint."

Is this saying that the bishops' counselors have to be elders but he can also call high priests who are not his counselors?
Or is it saying that his counselors can be either elders or high priests???

Comment: Show a link or more context.

Comment: The more obvious reading is "They shall be laid before (the bishop and his counselors) or (two of the elders) or (high priests), whichever he decides to appoint." However, "They shall be laid before the bishop and his counselors (who are two of the elders), or high priests ... is not an impossible/unacceptable interpretation (purely from the way English works). The ambiguity occurs because the comma is pressed into doing so many jobs (here listing and perhaps marking an appositive). The script needs rewriting.

Comment: Assuming that Marius is correct in his statement of the original text and that it it is what OP really wants an answer for, who on earth has upvoted this question, which isn't then accurate?

Comment: This comes from the Doctrine and Covenants of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints Section 42 Verse 31.  In Marius' answer he found that in the Millennial Star the third comma was excluded (the comma before the or) but in the D&C there are three commas, does this third comma then change the meaning.  I agree that with only two commas either the elders or high priests are considered counselors, but with three does this close the counselor group and open up a new group?  Thank You for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct text is here:

[The Latter-Day Saints Millennial Star - Volumes 5-7](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ymktAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22They%20shall%20be%20laid%20before%20the%20bishop%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VW46VavXGbG1sATby4G4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22They%20shall%20be%20laid%20before%20the%20bishop%22&f=false)  - Page 51
1845

... as ye impart of your substance to the poor, ye will do it unto me — and **they [a covenant and a deed which cannot be broken - giving the poor their riches/properties] shall be laid before the bishop of my church and his counsellors, two of the elders or high priests, such as he shall or has appointed and set apart for that purpose.**

My reading taking into account the apposition is that:

his counsellors = two of the elders or high priests, which are designated by him
[the bishop], but as  Edwin Ashworth notes, there are no guarantees:-)

Comment: This is why lawyers hate commas - they rarely make things clearer. It would be clearer with "the bishop and his counsellors - who shall be two of the elders or high priests such as he shall appoint or has appointed...

Comment: This comes from the Doctrine and Covenants of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints Section 42 Verse 31. In Marius' answer he found that in the Millennial Star the third comma was excluded (the comma before the or) but in the D&C there are three commas, does this third comma then change the meaning. I agree that with only two commas either the elders or high priests are considered counselors, but with three does this close the counselor group and open up a new group?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the comma after "elders" alters things considerably—and for the worse, in point of intelligibility. Whereas the 1845 version cited in Marius Hancu's very helpful link clearly treats "two of the elders or high priests" as an appositive of "his counsellors," the additional comma makes only "two of the elders" an appositive of "his counsellors," with "high priests left over as an alternative to "the bishop and his counsellors," OR it presents all three options ("the bishop," "his counsellors," and "high priests" as coequal alternatives, OR it doesn't know what it's doing.

Looking a bit more closely at the periodical that Marius Hancu found, I note that it is *The Latter-Day Saints' Millennial Star* for September 1844, and that the article where the quoted language appears is "[History of Joseph Smith](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ymktAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22They%20shall%20be%20laid%20before%20the%20bishop%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VW46VavXGbG1sATby4G4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22They%20shall%20be%20laid%20before%20the%20bishop%22&f=false)," quoting a revelation recorded by Joseph Smith in February 1831. The entire paragraph runs as follows:

> If the lovest me, thou shalt serve me, and keep all my commandments. And, behold, thou wilt remember the poor, and consecrate of thy properties for their support that which thou hast to impart unto them, with a covenant and deed which cannot be broken—and inasmuch as ye impart your substance to the poor, ye will do it unto  me—and they shall be laid before the bishop of my church and his counsellors, two of the elders or high priests, such as he shall or has appointed and set apart for that purpose.

The report, though it appeared less than 14 years after the original revelations, might have introduced a typographical error that the official *Doctrine and Covenants* has corrected; but it is unsettling that the earlier version makes more sense than the later one. Perhaps the *Millennial Star* removed the comma after "elders" that had been in the original revelation, and the church later restored it, on the theory that a revelation should not be subject to copyediting for clarity. In any case, the three-comma version is ambiguous and the two-comma version is not.